# Nginx Enable HTTPS/SSL when forwarding to other URL

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-web-services, https

Currently, I'm working with an AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance, running a Node.js app on port 3000, that has an Nginx reverse proxy. I have been trying to enable HTTPS and add a SSL certificate and I've been successful in that I don't get any errors in the nginx.conf file. However, I am redirecting my main website, "example.com" to the public DNS of the AWS server and when I try to load the "http://example.com" or "https://example.com" page, I get a "Unable to Connect" error from Firefox, which is my testing browser. Also when I run `sudo nginx -t`, there are no syntactical errors in the configuration file and when I check the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file it is empty. Below is my current nginx.conf file.

Update: I changed server_name from `example.com` to the public DNS of my server, lets call it `amazonaws.com`. Now, when I type in `https://amazonaws.com` the page loads and the SSL certificate shows up when running the website through ssllabs.com. However, when I type in `amazonaws.com` or `http://amazonaws.com` I get a blank page like before.

```
user root;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  # max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections / 4
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  ## Size Limits
  #client_body_buffer_size   8k;
  #client_header_buffer_size 1k;
  #client_max_body_size      1m;
  #large_client_header_buffers 4 4k/8k;

  # Timeouts, do not keep connections open longer then necessary to reduce
  # resource usage and deny Slowloris type attacks.
  client_body_timeout      3s; # maximum time between packets the client can pause when sending nginx any data
  client_header_timeout    3s; # maximum time the client has to send the entire header to nginx
  keepalive_timeout       75s; # timeout which a single keep-alive client connection will stay open
  send_timeout            9s; # maximum time between packets nginx is allowed to pause when sending the client data
  spdy_keepalive_timeout 123s; # inactivity timeout after which the SPDY connection is closed
  spdy_recv_timeout        4s; # timeout if nginx is currently expecting data from the client but nothing arrives

  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  charset utf-8;
  ignore_invalid_headers on;
  max_ranges 0;
  msie_padding off;
  open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=2h;
  open_file_cache_errors on;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
  open_file_cache_valid 1h;
  reset_timedout_connection on;
  server_tokens off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;

  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

 ## Proxy settings. Make sure the "timeout"s are long enough to
 ## take account of over loaded back end servers or long running
 ## cgi scripts. If the proxy timeout is too short the nginx proxy
 ## might re-request the data over and over again, putting more
 ## load on the back end server.
  proxy_max_temp_file_size    0;
  proxy_connect_timeout      900;
  proxy_send_timeout         900;
  proxy_read_timeout         900;
  proxy_buffer_size          4k;
  proxy_buffers              4 32k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
  proxy_intercept_errors     on;

  # backend applications
  upstream nodes {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
  }

  map $scheme $hsts_header {
      https   max-age=31536000;
  }

  server {
    server_name amazonaws.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    server_name amazonaws.com;
    listen 443 ssl spdy default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.key;

    # enable session resumption to improve https performance
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    # Enables server-side protection from BEAST attacks, disables SSLv3 and ciphers chosen for forward secrecy and compatibility
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

    # Enable OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/private/example_com_full.crt;

    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security $hsts_header;

    expires 1h;
    server_name amazonaws.com;

    # everything else goes to backend node apps
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://nodes;

      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have nothing with the forwarding. You're probably just getting errors on the actual example.com site, but not showing them.

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin I'm not quite sure what you mean. Without the addition of the SSL lines in the nginx.conf file, everything ran fine. And by everything I mean that the node.js app itself works fine, the public DNS of the server loaded the webpage fine and example.com loaded fine. However, when I added the SSL lines and redirection from HTTP to HTTPS, everything stopped working...

Comment: The thing is, phrases like "everything works fine" and "nothing works" don't describe anything. Or, if you want, they describe the same situation observed by an optimist and a pessimist. Does the `https://example.com`, when entered in browser address bar directly, show an empty page ?

Comment: You should not use SSLv3, as it is not secure anymore. What does `/var/log/nginx/error.log` show after an empty page?

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin I apologize for being a little vague in my phrasing. I'm inexperienced when it comes to nginx and routing.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen If not SSLv3, what configuration options for SSL would you recommend? Also the /var/log/nginx/error.log file is empty and the command nginx -t shows no syntacticaly errors.

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin  When I try to load the `https://example.com` page Firefox says "Unable to Connect". The same occurs with the `http://example.com` page.

Comment: so at least your https web server doesn't work, may be it's not even running.

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin No, its running. If you read my initial post, I specifically state that when I go to `https://amazonaws.com` the website displays correctly. However, redirection from `http://amazonaws.com` is not working and `https://example.com` is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin Also is what I'm asking for even feasible? `example.com` url-frame redirects to `https://amazonaws.com`. With this setup is it even possible to put the `example.com` SSL certificate on the `amazonaws.com` server?

Comment: so it's web server serving `http://example.com` doesn't work.  at least it's ssl part. check it.

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin Can you be a little more specific about what to check? Perhaps write an answer?

Comment: So you are redirecting from `http://A` to `https://B`. in the same time you are stating that neither `https://B`, nor `http://B` don't work. so you should check either the web-server at B and fix it, or stop redirecting to a site that's actually down.

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin No, not quite. I'm saying that `https://B.com` works fine and that `http://A.com` work fine. However for some reason `https://A.com` is not working and on top of that `http://B.com` is redirecting to `https://A.com` even though thats nowhere in the conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `server` block for HTTP is missing `server_name` directive, and there is no `server` block with `default_server` directive specified.

The default behavior of nginx is to match requests without `Host:` headers in that case.

Your configuration should work after adding `server_name` directive to the HTTP server block.

Comment: I updated my nginx conf file with your suggestions as well as other things but I'm getting the same problem or at least a similar one. If you take a look at my last comment on my post, you'll see the problem I'm having now. Also is what I'm trying to accomplish even feasible? `example.com` url-frame redirects to `https://amazonaws.com`. With this setup is it even possible to put the `example.com` SSL certificate on the `amazonaws.com` server?

Comment: Correction: everything redirects and works properly now except `https://example.com`.

Comment: Turns out I had problems I had been incorrectly redirecting at my domain registrar, Namecheap. When I fixed that, everything started working.